# what is "This array-name does not have a '[' behind it "?

Tags: java

```
class Input{
  static char[] InputALine( String c ) throws Throwable{
  char []sLine = new char[100];
  if(c.equlas("a")){
    int i = 0 ;
    sIn = G.sIn.ReadChar();
    while ( sIn != '.' ) {
      sLine[i] = sIn;
      i++;
      sIn = G.sIn.ReadChar();
    }
  }
   return sLine; <-- problem
  }
}
```

error:

```
sLine

This array-name does not have a '[' behind it
```

I'm new to Java, I use `return sLine` and `return sLine[]`.

It still doesn't work.I want to return char array from InputALine( .. )

I don't know what's going on.

Comment: `c.euqlas("a")` <-- is this a typo for `equals()` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I made a typo.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I changed it

Comment: What is "it" that's "showing"?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- a error

Comment: What tool is generating the error message? I don't believe that this comes from javac (and indeed when mocking `G.sIn.ReadChar()` I can compile it without problems.)

Comment: If you want to return the char array you write `return sLine;` - that is what the java compiler expects and accepts. If your (unknown) compiler rejects this line then it is not a valid java compiler. And out of curiosity I would like to know what compiler you are trying to use to compile java source code.

Answer (score 1):

you should write:

```
char[] sLine = new char[100];
```

instead of

```
char []sLine = new char[100];
```

you should use a space to separate [] and variable name otherwise the whole thing ([]sLine) will be perceived as a variable name

Comment: If so, then this question is just a typo, and you should be voting to close.  Do not answer it.

Comment: you are right, but this confuses him. also I don't know how to vote this to close..

Comment: Unfortunately, not this problem